# Android: Supporting smart phone only

Tags: android, screen-resolution

My application is live on google play.
I want to make it compatible with smart phone only.For that I have done like this...

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"/>
 <supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

And my problem is market does not filter for tablet (mdpi tablet like Samsung tab1).one thing is that some phone like WVGA800* (480x800)(mdpi),WVGA800** (480x800)(ldpi) in large screen and some tablet also comes in this range.So i want to allow phones not tablet then what should be the solution???

I found some help from here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
 <supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:largestWidthLimitDp="320"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

Will it work on market??..I am asking with this kind of solution if anybody is having experience of this.My problem is i can not test by uploading new version of application.please help me..

Alternative solution will do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To test if it works, upload the APK and check the "supported devices" in the "Product details" tab. You do not have to save the project after doing this; just do not hit "Save" after you're done checking. You can even exclude single devices through this interface.

Comment: IT should work, but might fail for devices like the Original Samsung Galaxy Tab 7 inches.

Comment: @Eric let me try... but i never get uploaded in one shot. :) google love this error "The server could not process your apk. Try again."

Answer (score 5):

Have you added 'compatiable-screens' tag to your AndroidManifest.xml? It's what Google Play uses to filtering devices based on screen sizes.

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />      
    <!-- large screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
```

By not including android:screenSize="xlarge", your apps will not show up for 10.1" tablets. android:screenSize="large" is a little bit tricky. It could be devices up to 7" so Galaxy Tab 7" falls into this category. But I am not sure if the newer Galaxy S3, or Galaxy Nexus with 4.75" screen falls into 'large' screen category.

Try adding the above snippet to your AndroidManifest.xml, and if Google Play includes 7" tablets in the supported devices list, you can always remove them.

Comment: Will it support large WVGA800* (480x800) (mdpi) and large
WVGA854* (480x854)(mdpi) ??? listed in table http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing

Comment: Just add android:screenDensity="mdpi" to android:screenSize="large" and it will show up for those resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

All android tablets run on HONEYCOMB (`level 11, 12, 13`). You can disallow the installation on Honeycomb. Now, you might wonder how to exclude some specific API levels from the middle of the API level sequence (i.e.: 11,12 and 13 from 1-15) with using the `min-sdk` and `max-sdk` specifiers, as they don't support ranges.

here's the solution to that :

> You can do that when you publish it to the Google Play. In Android
>   Developer Console while uploading application come to APK files tab
>   and check advanced mode. It lets you to upload 2 apk files with
>   different sdk levels ranges. But don't forget to set different version
>   codes for them.
>
> All statistics in the console will be aggregated for both apk files as
>   it is one.

So, you can create two apks (one of them supprting level 1 to 10 and the other supporting level 14 and 15 ) and that will prevent your application to be installed on Tablets. :-)

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498591/dis-allow-installation-on-specific-api-level/11498694#11498694)

Comment: Thank you for your answer... but There are many tablet that does not falls into API level 11,12,13. Problem is tablet those density matches with smart phones and theirs' resolution is big... once again thank you for giving me your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered there are not exact or Best ways.

- Configurations in Manifest
- Device filter in Google Play

Additionally Maintain Special note on google play like Phone Only in Application name displayed on Google Play.

For most 7" screen falling under large screen capability, your application can be used on 7" Tablet.
If you have two APK's uploaded , google play take care of right APK for your device.

If your application is Phone only and explicitly use  Phone feature which is not available on Tablet in that case you can add code check which will not allow user to move further even if installed.

As you are not interested in Tablet you don't care.

Best practice is assume 7" Tablet falling under large screen phone should be consider in dev effort.
As android tablet have all features including calling ( VOIP) available.