# Dis-allow installation on specific API Level

Tags: android, compatibility

How to dis-allow my app to run on a specific API level? i know about the 3 specifiers in [uses-sdk](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)  tag in the manifest. But that can't produce a logic i want to implement.

For eg: i want to allow my application to be installed on `Level 4` to `Level 10`, dis-allow for `Level 11` to `Level 13` and again allow for `Level 14` and `Level 15`.

Is that possible?

Comment: You can't do this for installation. You can set minSdk to 4, and maxSdk to 15. Then you have to check for API level in the code to prevent execution. If they run your app on API 11, just pop up a error dialog and quit the app.

Comment: I think you do not want to allow the user to install on `Tablets` for this you can do like `<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="false"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />` in your manifest file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that when you publish it to the Google Play.
In Android Developer Console while uploading application come to APK files tab and check advanced mode. It lets you to upload 2 apk files with different sdk levels ranges. But don't forget to set different version codes for them.

All statistics in the console will be aggregated for both apk files as it is one.

Comment: aha! that sounds like the solution!

Comment: I am not sure it is perfect or not? But I have a doubt that, there are some tablets in market that runs `android 2.2 or less then <3.0` in that cases it will fails?

Comment: It will available for that API level ranges that you set. If you upload apk for 2.2 it will be available for 2.2 devices whether it tablet or phone. And it is proper behavior.

Comment: If you are searching solution for cutting tablets you can restrict tablets by setting android:xlargeScreens="false" in supports-screens tag of the Manifest file

Answer (score 0):

You can create two apks (Not advisable). One that support for api level 4 to 10 & another one for api level 14 & 15 and you need to activate both the apks in your developer console. The Play store decide which apk to install based on android manifest xml.